# How many Intel CPU devices have Nougat or later?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, 8.0-oreo, x86-processors

From the [official dashboard](https://developer.android.com//about//dashboards) or other resources, I cannot derive how many (if any) real commercially available devices with Intel CPU have Nougat or higher installed (or preinstalled).

As Android developer, I want to know how many regular users may suffer if I choose not to support these devices (*due to [ffmpeg text relocations in assembly](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/195), if you want to know why*).

I don't care about the emulators, or [android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) deeply respected community. These people have much better alternatives for video recoding.

Comment: It isn't quite easy to tell whether this question is off-topic

Comment: "deeply respected experiments" - the questions we get about android-x86 show there's actually quite a determined community who play mobile games or use messaging apps on their PCs. Whether those people are relevant to you is another matter, of course.

Comment: I've previously written an answer for [What Percentage of Android Devices Runs on x86 Architecture?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/what-percentage-of-android-devices-runs-on-x86-architecture/186348#186348) - you should be able to get a rough idea.