# What Percentage of Android Devices Run on a 64-bit Architecture?

Tags: android-versions

How many Android devices are using the ARM64 or x86_64 architectures, and how many are using 64-bit versions of Android that can run 64-bit apps?

My assumption right now is that it's still worth supporting 32-bit versions of Android for mobile apps, but these days more and more devices are 64-bit and make use of several GB of RAM. As of this month, Google is now [requiring that new Android apps have 64-bit versions](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#), so I'm wondering for how long it will be worth supporting both architectures.

Additionally, how powerful are average high-end 32-bit devices? Even if the marketshare of 32-bit devices is high, it could be worth dropping support if most 32-bit devices won't run any intensive apps or games anyway.

This question is related to another question about [x86 usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/what-percentage-of-android-devices-runs-on-x86-architecture).

Comment: App development related questions get better reception at https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not yet been able to view recent statistics, but
according to this [article](https://www.extremetech.com/mobile/260880-google-will-require-future-android-apps-64-bit-support-updated-apis) published end of 2017:

> The ARMv8 instruction set architecture rolled out 64-bit hardware support in 2014, and now almost every new Android device can run 64-bit code (but only 40 percent of active devices)

From this ARM's [blog post](https://www.arm.com/blogs/blueprint/android-64bit-future-mobile):

> Nearly 90 percent of today’s Android devices deploy a 64-bit capable version of the OS (version 5.0 and above).

Statistics on the percentage of OS used can be checked [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) and [here](https://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions).

Comment: The "Distribution dashboard" (your first "here" link) doesn't actually have information about 32-bit vs 64-bit, but it does have Android version marketshare. Where can I find information of which Android versions support 64-bit (and are there any that are only 64-bit?)

Comment: Any idea how this is today? I use a 2015 sm-j700m locked on 32bits than can run many games from playstore. I think i should use ue4 to create 32bits game too (ue5 is 64bits only). 32bits seems still very alive right?

Comment: @VeganEye I have not seen recent stats. But on the link to the [Distribution dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards), it is stated that "If you want to see statistics just for the devices on which users are running your app, you can use the Google Play Console". I don't know if it shows the percent of 32-bit and 64-bit devices.