# How is the market divided between Android CPU architectures?

Tags: hardware, cpu

There is a [very similar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/what-percentage-of-android-devices-runs-on-x86-architecture) question on this site but it is outdated and contains no/outdated statistical sources.

I want to know how is the market divided between arm64-v7a, arm64-v8a, armeabi (I know it's deprecated now), x86, etc...

The best answer would be if there is some statistic made that shows the percentages of each type.

The reason I am asking is because I am a mobile developer and I want to know if I make an app that runs on 64-bit processors only, then what percentage of people won't be able to use the app.

Comment: Tlherke is no arm64-v7a architecture, only arm-v7 (32 bit). And armeabi is an alias for arm-v7a. x86 is effectively dead and is only relevant for emulators (and may be Android on Chromebooks? Not sure how many x86 Chromebooks exist). For new Android phones and tablets my guess would be 99% arm64-v8a (some may use armv9a but that is effectively just an extension to arm-v8a).

Comment: @Robert pardon my ignorance, thanks for the info, so you're saying if I build an android app that supports only 64 bit processors it will run on the vast majority (your guess is >99%) of the devices? (Do know somewhere we can see usage statistics?)

Comment: No I did not say that the market share is 99% of arm64 devices, I said that today are, except may be from some special Android devices, all phones supporting arm64-v8a and for the last few years this is also true. But if you consider older devices sold may be 5 years ago an older than you may still find arm-v7a only devices.

Comment: that answers my question, thanks, you can post an answer as well if you have some percentages

Comment: You also need to consider that OS and that hardware is used by others, i.e. I can run the Android OS on my PC via virtualbox/vmware player, Windows and Linux can also run on Arm CPU devices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on researching the update to the Unity Stats from [Khemraj Sharma's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202022/44325), apparently there was an update to the Unity Analytics called Market Insights that also shows the CPU distribution.

From [Where's the Unity stats page gone?](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wheres-the-unity-stats-page-gone.514106/), [trucn, a Unity Technology staff posted](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wheres-the-unity-stats-page-gone.514106/#post-3607438) (2018),

> Good news! We've brought back some of the data from the old hwstats page in the Operate Dashboard. We have plans to expand our offering in the future and offer more detailed breakdowns and metrics, but this isn't on the near near horizon yet.
>
> If you go to the Unity Dashboard Operate Tab and navigate into any project, it's under Analytics > Market Insights (I know, not super intuitive and don't ask why it's living here :p)
> [View attachment 293142](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/293142/)
>
> The URL path is:
> `https://operate.dashboard.unity3d.com/organizations/<YOUR ORG ID HERE>/projects/<YOUR PROJECT ID HERE>/hwstats`

**As of Q3 2022, the reported distribution for Android is**:

[image]

| CPU | Percentage (%) |
| --- | --- |
| ARM64 | 63.63% |
| ARMv7 | 19.09% |
| x86 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 | 0.07% |
| x86-64 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX | 0.03% |
| x86-64 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 | 0.03% |
| x86-64 | 0.02% |
| Intel Pentium | <0.01% |
| Others | 17.14% |

---

<sup>(Note that the current URL for Market Insight is `https://dashboard.unity3d.com/organizations/<YOUR ORG ID HERE>/projects/<YOUR PROJECT ID HERE>/analytics/hwstats` and it's not linked to the new Gaming Service dashboard)</sup>

Comment: are these stats dependent on the unity account?

Comment: @Haidar no, the Market Insight is global. I just created a developer account without having any working projects.

Comment: Do you know what the 17% "Others" actually consists of? I'm sure it isn't MIPS[64], the only other Android hardware platforms that have existed.

Comment: @JohnDallman unfortunately I don't have a clue either, and for some reason, I currently have difficulty in accessing that page again with my account.

Comment: @AndrewT. Taking another look at that graph, I'm pretty sure it's an a reporting error. There hasn't been a new Android platform that grew from 0% in 3Q21 to 17% in 3Q22. However, that's rather similar to the growth of Android 12 market share for the same period; if Unity was failing to recognise Android 12 hardware for some reason, that would fit. Another possibility would be a failure to recognise ARMv9, but the dates don't line up.